# How to use screenrc bindkey on MacOS with iterm?

Tags: linux

I have a screenrc with things like:

```
bindkey -d \033n stuff "screen -x chdir \$PWD;screen^M"
```

But nothing works well on MacOS. Something is grabbing the keybindings and it is only sometimes works. Want single key terminal emulation like iterm or terminal on linux but with screen for remote sessions.

I am using `sed -n l` but it doesn't print everything.

I used to have this working from windows to linux (something like ctrl-n for new tab, ctrl-1,2,3,4,5... for the tabs).